# Bash not terminating python script

Tags: python, bash, multithreading

I'm trying to run a simple animated python script while bash executes some files. However the animation script isn't properly terminating once the bash script is done.

The python script works perfectly. If I use a different animation that runs natively in Bash, the bash script works. But if I get bash to run the python script, it runs forever?

Bash Script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Don't leave animation running if files executed.
unset anim_pid
trap 'kill $anim_pid 2>/dev/null' EXT INT
# Get animation script
animation() {
      python "/home/solebay/Project/loading_animation.py"
}

animation & anim_pid=$!

# Scripts to execute
python "/home/solebay/Project/script_a" & pid1=$!
python "/home/solebay/Project/script_b" & pid2=$!

# wait for tasks to finish
wait $pid1 $pid2
kill $anim_pid 2>/dev/null

printf '\n *** End of script ***\n'
```

Python `loading_animation.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import itertools
import threading
import time
import sys

# Please wait message
msg = "\nPlease wait a moment..."
for idx, i in enumerate(msg):
    if idx <= 19:
        sys.stdout.write(i)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.02)
    else:
       sys.stdout.write(i)
       sys.stdout.flush()
       time.sleep(0.6)
# Spinning part
for c in itertools.cycle(['|', '/', '-', '\\']):
    sys.stdout.write('\rPlease wait a moment... ' + c)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Ultimately it doesn't work and the animation mis-prints and then spins forever. Is this because I'm trying to use multithreading and then leaving threads open? Alternatively, are never-ending loading scripts a terrible idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are [putting the function in the background](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Putting_functions_in_background) and then killing that function, but not the command that's running inside.

Instead you can invoke the script without wrapping it by a function:

```sh
python "/home/solebay/Project/loading_animation.py" &
anim_pid=$!
```

Comment: May I ask, why the variable `anim_pid` is not evaluated in the trap? How else can we pass variables to the trap? I guess putting them into the environment wouldn't help either.

Comment: @user1934428 You are right, I was mistaken, it will be evaluated when invoked.